# Куда на android устанавливаются приложенрие на kivy из apk

Tags: python, android, kivy, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Сделал по инструкции в интернете из своего kivy приложения apk с помощью buildozer, перенёс и установил на смартфон под android, а оно суде по всему связь между python файлами потеряло, из-за чего нормально не работает.

Я захотел посмотреть, как это выглядит в установленном виде, что-бы хоть что-нибудь понять, начал смотреть в android/data и android/obb, где все приложения обычно находятся, но не смог найти куда он установился, (в buldozer init файле ничего про место установке не нашёл).

Куда он мог установится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в **/data/data/com.(author).(appname)** *(нужен root для просмотра)*

Comment: вы имеете в виду root права?

Comment: да, о них и речь

Comment: тогда понятно, благодарю за ответ!